# DB Schema for translations

Tags: sql, sqlite

In one of my applications I need to save translations into a database. Each of them is identified by three parameters. A code, the language and the type of the text. My first idea was to just save them all into one table in the following way:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS translations("\
  "code INT NOT NULL,"\
  "language char(3) NOT NULL,"\
  "type char(20) NOT NULL,"\
  "text Text,"\
  "PRIMARY KEY(code,language,type)) WITHOUT ROWID;";
```

This makes the query quite easy using:

```
"SELECT text FROM translations WHERE code=? AND language=? AND type=? LIMIT 1;"
```

However since I did not work with databases before i am not quite sure whether there is a better way to do this. (I am especially not sure whether it's a good thing to have multiple primary keys).
Does it make sence to split this into multiple tables?

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend keeping a primary key.  In SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS translations (
    translation_id int auto_increment,  -- becomes a synonym for rowid
    code INT NOT NULL,
    language char(3) NOT NULL,
    type char(20) NOT NULL,
    text Text,
    UNIQUE (code, language, type)
);
```

The primary key is handy when you want to delete a particular row.  Using an auto-increment also lets you see the order that things are added in (although I would also add a `createdAt` timestamp).

Comment: Why can't I just use ```DELETE FROM translations WHERE code=? AND language=? AND type=?;```? I do not really understand the advantage I get by using the auto incrementing translation_id

Comment: @maxbachmann . . . You can do that.  And you can do that if you have an integer primary key.  I just find it easier to work with a unique identifying column rather than multiple columns.